# Define Data Property Expression in Protege

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, protege

I am trying to model an ontology about hiking with protege. There I have Destinations, which can for example be a trail (subclass of Destination). As a another subclass of Destination I'd like to have long-distance trails and only trails with a certain distance/length are long distance trails.

To achieve this I added a data property (has)kmDistance for trails.
Then I wanted to add an expression like:

```
equivalent to

Destination and (kmDistance value > 100)
```

to long-distance trails,
to add all instances with more than 100 kilometers. But I'm struggling to write this expression, as soon as I write something like min, or >= etc. protege does not accept the input.

Would be great if someone could help me out!

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working now, the solution was just to pot "xsd:" before the datatype "integer". Now it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: what about range ? greater and less than